# Apache shutdown unexpectedly wont starting

Tags: apache, xampp

I have this error above
Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.

I change httpd.conf Listen 80 to 8080 port and server name also SSL port  on httpd-ssl.conf and not working

Answer (score 0):

Due to many reason this error occurs ,

1) Port block (80,433)
2) php version (x86) , apache(x64) version mismatch vice versa
3) Point correct php version in the system environmental variable

To get detailed error try to run

**apache_start.bat**
**mysql_staer.bat**

In my case am facing problem with **XAMPP control panel V3.2.4** portable version
It says "apache server root should be valid"

**setup_xampp.bat**    after running  this bat file everything solved by itself

[image]